# PHP is claiming $db is undefinded but it is defined

Tags: php

I have the global set in the very top of my script but whenever I run it, it tells me that $db is undefined.

```
global $db;
$db = '';
$db = new Database($dbname, $host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, 'utf8', true, "Database Error");

function tryLogin($username, $password)
{

    $row = $db->fetch_row("SELECT id, username, password, salt, email FROM users WHERE username = ?", true, array($username));

    if(genPassWithSalt($POST['password'], $row['salt']) === $row['password']) 
    { 
        return $row;    
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php See "The _global_ keyword" part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variable `$db` is not accessible from inside the function; consider changing the function signature to:

```
function tryLogin($db, $username, $password)
```

And to call:

```
tryLogin($db, 'hello', 'pwd');
```

In addition to that, the `global $db;` statement at the top of your code can be removed, it's not doing anything useful right now.

Comment: +1 for passing $db as an argument rather than polluting the global namespace

Comment: I would recommend this as the preferred way to do things.

Answer (score 4):

Your `global` should be inside your function to have connection available

```
function tryLogin($username, $password)
{
    global $db;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `global $db;` inside your function too.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP each function has it own [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). That means that variables defined outside of the function is not available inside of the function. You need to either pass it into the function or make it global.

```
function tryLogin($username, $password, $db) 
{
    // code
}
```

or

```
function tryLogin($username, $password)
{
    global $db;
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

also have a look at closure on lambda function, as in your case it's a db i think you want let it global but closure can be a cleaner solution in most case

```
$c = 'World';
$myfunction = function ($a,$b) use ($c) {
    echo "Hello, $c!\n";
};
```